# Error on ldap auth with laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I've followed the instructions at https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel with a brand new laravel project and I can't seem to get it to work. I have done the following:

Added the following line to app.php

```
Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider::class,
Adldap\Laravel\AdldapAuthServiceProvider::class
```

Changed the driver to LDAP in auth.php

```
'users' => [
        'driver' => 'adldap',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

However when I try to login I get the following error:

```
Use of undefined constant LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION - assumed 'LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION'
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's a syntax error. You are trying to use constant `LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION` but it is not defined. By default, PHP throws a warning and uses the undefined constant name as a string.

Search where you are using that undfined constant and either define it or replace it with the version of your LDAP server.

Also, if you are trying to do *adminless* LDAP authentication, you might be interested in this:

[laravel-simple-ldap-auth](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/laravel-simple-ldap-auth)